# Copying local variable into vector in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust, and I'm trying to copy a local variable into a vector. Here's my attempt:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct DFAItem<'a> {
    reading: usize,
    production: &'a grammar::CFGProduction<'a>,
    next_terminal: i32,
}

fn add_nonterminal<'a>(cfg: &'a grammar::CFG, nonterminal: usize, itemset: &'a mut Vec<DFAItem>) {
    let productions = &cfg.productions[nonterminal];
    for prod in productions {
        let item = DFAItem {
            reading: 0,
            production: prod,
            next_terminal: 0,
        };
        itemset.push(item); //here, I get a lifetime error (lifetime 'a required).
        match prod.rhs[0] {
            grammar::Symbol::Nonterminal(x) if x != nonterminal => add_nonterminal(cfg, x, itemset),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I can't modify the lifetime of item to make it match itemset, so what I'm trying to do is copy item into the vector, so that would have the vector's lifetime. Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Also, anybody know the syntax so that I could change cfg to have at least as long of a lifetime as itemset instead of the same? Would I just declare a second lifetime or is there a better way to do it?

EDIT: here are the definitions of CFG and CFGProduction:

```
pub enum Symbol {
    Terminal(i32),
    Nonterminal(usize),
}

pub struct CFGProduction<'a> {
    pub nonterminal: usize,
    pub rhs: &'a Vec<Symbol>,
}

pub struct CFG<'a> {
    pub terminals: Vec<i32>,
    pub productions: Vec<Vec<CFGProduction<'a>>>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the lifetime of the `itemset` vec is not relevant and doesn't need to be constrained to anything. Second, `CFG` and `DFAItem` have generic lifetime parameters, so they should be indicated as such when using them in function arguments.

Here's my take, there's two big lifetimes involved here:

- `'a`: the lifetime needed by `CFGProduction`'s
- `'b`: the lifetime of `cfg` and its subsequent references stored in `DFAItem`s

Therefore, `DFAItem` should have two lifetimes:

```
struct DFAItem<'a, 'b> {
    // ...
    production: &'b grammar::CFGProduction<'a>,
    // ...
}
```

and `add_nonterminal()`'s signature would look like so:

```
fn add_nonterminal<'a, 'b>(cfg: &'b grammar::CFG<'a>, nonterminal: usize, itemset: &mut Vec<DFAItem<'a, 'b>>) {
    // ...
}
```

With these lifetime changes, the function body compiles as is. See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eeb5beb0f030589ae0d211534fc0838f).

---

You can choose *not* to do that and just use `'a` for everything:

```
struct DFAItem<'a> {
    // ...
    production: &'a grammar::CFGProduction<'a>,
    // ...
}

fn add_nonterminal<'a>(cfg: &'a grammar::CFG<'a>, nonterminal: usize, itemset: &mut Vec<DFAItem<'a>>) {
    // ...
}
```

but I'd advise against it. Types with the pattern `&'a Type<'a>`, where the generic lifetime is linked with itself can cause problems down the line; especially with mutability.